# subquery returned more than 1 value in the following query

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that does a `select *` from book table, using a subquery.

My query is :

```
SELECT A.Titel, A.Preis
FROM Album A
WHERE A.Veroffentlichsdatum < (SELECT A.Veroffentlichsdatum
                               FROM Album A
                               INNER JOIN LiedAlbum ON LiedAlbum.IdAlbum = A.Id 
                                                    AND LiedAlbum.IdLied = (SELECT L.Id 
                                                                            FROM Lied L 
                                                                            WHERE L.Titel IN ('Lifeislife')))
```

What should I change to get rid of this error?

Comment: `SELECT L.Id from Lied L where L.Titel in ('Lifeislife'))` can return more than 1 value; add a `TOP 1`

Comment: Tried, not worked

Comment: Also needed for `where A.Veroffentlichsdatum < ( SELECT`

Comment: I don't know with what value(s) you should compare but subquery should return exactly 1 value for comparison operators. So try returning TOP 1 with your subquery. i.e. `select TOP 1 A.Veroffentlichsdatum From . . .`

Comment: or if you want to compare based on multiple values, you would be needing to change your logic and where clause to use operators that support comparison with multipe values e.g. `IN`

Comment: @PeterSmith, how do you know that TOP 1 is the correct solution?

Comment: @AndiToma112, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: You are trying to "less than" compare one value with a bunch of values (the subquery). What do you want to do?

Comment: Unless LiedAlbum and Lied have some relationship it is not possible to prevent selecting the wrong Lied. Especially if the same song (Lied) appears multiple times with different IDs. It is a chasm trap.

Comment: @jarlh Correct,  I don't know that `TOP 1` is correct; I was attempting to show the nature of the problem but was also eating breakfast at the same time and trying to be brief!

Comment: @PeterSmith, breakfast coffee is the solution to most problems!

Comment: As per other comments, the issue is trying to say 'less than' multiple dates, when that operator can only compare one date with one other. Without further clarification and/ or sample data, I would guess you want to select MIN(A.Veroffentlichsdatum) or MAX(A.Veroffentlichsdatum) to see if it was published before others that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do. Since it is the same table why don't you just join them without subquery?
The only modification right now I can suggest is the below :

```
LiedAlbum.IdLied =(SELECT L.Id from Lied L where L.Titel in ('Lifeislife'))
```

into

```
exists (select 1 from Lied where Titel = 'Lifeislife' and LiedAlbum.IdLied = Lied.Id)
```